# Angular 7 app is continuously crashing the browser when sign in with a particular google account. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: angular, browser, frontend, browser-cache, google-account

App is getting crashed when using a particular google account, the sync is on

when checked cpu usage in performance monitor its utilizing 100% cpu

its working when resetting the browser data, but after a week the page become unresponsive but working fine in incognito.

I have unsubscribed all the subs, local storage is being cleared, no console errors.

Comment: Is this a question or a general remark? :D

Comment: check subscriptions to unsubscribe, If you has setTimer or similar see to remove... Really It's hard try to help with no data

Comment: @PoulKruijt have updated the question with few more details

Comment: @Eliseo added few more detials

Comment: It's looks like you has a recursive function that has no end, or a infinite loop. It's possible you call an API with a parameters no valid that return a very large data, e.g. you think you ask about the users from 0 to 2000 and really are asking about all the users because don't send the 2000 -it's an stupid example, I know-...

Comment: @user8424583 open devtools and go to sources. When the cpu is running 100%, press F8 to halt execution. The stack trace will give you an idea where the loop is

Comment: Hi @PoulKruijt please check the new findings that ive added

Comment: Hi @Eliseo please check the new findings that ive added